# C++11: Is std::thread on linux depending on pthread library?

Tags: linux, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

I read that pthread is C library and is not compatible with C++ object model, especially when talking about exception handling.

So I wish to know on linux system, how gcc/clang implements `std::thread`, is it calling some linux native functions/kernel apis or something?

Also, how is `std::thread_local` implemented, related with `__thread`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ldd myExecutable` on compiler output to find out.

Both libstdc++ and libc++ apparently use pthreads, but they are not required to do that. Evidence of it can be found in native_handle methods documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/native_handle) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle). The documents say:

> Accesses the native handle of *this.
>
> The meaning and the type of the result of this function is implementation-defined. On a POSIX system, this may be a value of type pthread_cond_t*. On a Windows system, this may be a PCONDITION_VARIABLE.

and

> Returns the implementation defined underlying thread handle.

Comment: The OP asked about a specific implementation (*how gcc/clang implements `std::thread`*), so quoting the standard is not a relevant response.

Comment: I quoted the standard to establish, that it does not demand a specific implementation. I also answered that the libs use pthreads and the answer apparently satisfied OP, since it got accepted.

Answer (score 4):

> I read that pthread is C library and is not compatible with C++ object model, especially when talking about exception handling.

This information is inaccurate.

> how gcc/clang implements `std::thread`

They call a platform-specific thread creation function. On Linux it is `pthread_create`. You can call this function directly.

When a thread throws an exception and it is not caught `std::terminate` is called.

Note that your application must be compiled and linked with `-pthread` flag (using `-lpthread` is unnecessary and insufficient with both C and C++).

Answer (score 4):

> I read that pthread is C library and is not compatible with C++ object model, especially when talking about exception handling.

There's a statement in the neighborhood of this that is true, but this statement as written is not true.

There are two facts here.

1. If *YOU* call pthreads functions yourself, it is indeed just a C library, and you had better make sure you do everything correctly in regards to exception safety. If you pass function pointers to `pthread_create_...` and those functions will throw exceptions... your program can have big problems. That should be obvious, it will be true whenever you talk to a C library from C++.

   That does not mean it is impossible to use such a library with a C++ program!
2. pthread does not actually need to know about any of your objects, or any of their ctors or dtors, or any of that, in order to make your program multithreaded. All it needs to spawn a thread, is a function pointer, and that function pointer will have a completely C-compatible signature.

   When *the C++ compiler* calls pthreads functions in order to implement `std::thread`, the compiler is going to emit code that talks to pthread correctly. If it uses pthread in an illegal way to implement your C++ program, it's a bug in the compiler or standard library.